# Proof verification for $x^{10}+y^{10}+z^{10}\ge x^9+y^9+z^9$ (where $xyz=1$ and $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^+$)

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, solution-verification, muirhead-inequality

My teacher has shown me the following problem:

> **Problem.** Let $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}_+$ with $xyz=1$. Show that:$$x^{10}+y^{10}+z^{10}\ge x^9+y^9+z^9.$$

I think I solved the problem using Muirhead's Inequality (see below). The problem is that we haven't studied inequalities such as Muirhead, Schur, Hölder etc. so I reckon that the "expected" solution doesn't require them.

#### My (detailed) thought process

Let $$\sum_{\text{sym}}f(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)=\sum_{\pi\in S_n}f(x_{\pi(1)}, x_{\pi(2)},\dots,x_{\pi(n)}).$$

I began by rewriting the right hands side as

$$\begin{align}x^9+y^9+z^9&=\frac{x^9y^0z^0+x^9z^0y^0+y^9x^0z^0+y^9z^0x^0+z^9x^0y^0+z^9y^0x^0}{2}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{sym}}x^9y^0z^0.\end{align}$$

Then, my first instinct was to come up with a sequence $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ that majorizes $(9,0,0)$ in order to apply Muirhead's inequality to obtain $\sum_{\text{sym}}x^{10}y^0z^0$. Clearly, using the fact that $xyz=1$ must come into play now, and I wanted to get rid of two of the variables, so let's set $\gamma=\beta$, and we're left with the equations $\alpha +2\beta=9$ and $\alpha-\beta=10$, which leads to $\alpha=\frac{29}{3}$ and $\beta=-\frac{1}{3}$<sup>*</sup>. Since $(29/3, -1/3, -1/3) \succ (9, 0, 0)$<sup>**</sup>, by Muirhead ($x,y,z\neq 0$ since $xyz=1$):
$$x^9+y^9+z^9=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{sym}}x^9y^0z^0\le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{sym}}x^{29/3}y^{-1/3}z^{-1/3}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{sym}}x^{30/3}(xyz)^{-1/3}=x^{10}+y^{10}+z^{10}$$

#### Questions

- (*): Can Muirhead's Inequality be used for negative exponents? My question arises from the fact that some sources define the exponents as non-negative, while others just classify them as real numbers.
- (**), closely related to (*): Is majorization defined for sequences that contain negative numbers, or should this term only be used for sequences of non-negative reals? Again, I've seen several sources which disagree on this.
- (***) How would one solve this inequality *without* making use of Muirhead and other similar inequalities? I feel like it should be very simple but I fail to see any other solution right now. Additionally, is my proof correct? (I didn't get to use Muirhead much so my experience with it is close to zero)
- (****): Is it correct to generalize the problem as I did below? I noticed that a generalization is possible, so this led me to believe that my proof is incorrect, given the fact that only three numbers are given, and thus I may have missed something.

#### Possible generalization

> **Claim.** Let $(x_i)_{i=1}^n\in \mathbb{R}_+^n$ with $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i=1$. Then$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{10}\ge\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^9$$

**Proof.** Using a very similar argument,
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^9=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{\text{sym}}x_1^9\cdot x_2^0\cdot\dots\cdot x_n^0,$$
and the sequence of exponents that majorizes $(9,0,0,\dots,0)$ is $(\alpha,\beta,\beta,\dots,\beta)$ such that $10=\alpha-\beta$ and $(n-1)\beta+\alpha=9$, which gives $\beta=-1/n$ and $\alpha=10-1/n$. By Muirhead and using $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i=1$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^9\le \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{\text{sym}}x_1^{10-1/n}\cdot(x_2\cdot \dots\cdot x_n)^{-1/n}=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{10}.$$

Comment: Four questions is quite a few for one post

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ They're all closely related to the problem at hand, and two of them can be answered immediately by someone who has worked with those concepts a couple of times before (that's not the case for me, though).

Comment: The exponents do not need to be positive, see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My instinct is to use $xyz=1$ to rewrite the RHS as
$$x^9+y^9+z^9=x^{28/3}y^{1/3}z^{1/3}+x^{1/3}y^{28/3}z^{1/3}+x^{1/3}y^{1/3}z^{28/3}
$$
and then use AM/GM on each of these terms:
$$x^{28/3}y^{1/3}z^{1/3}\le\frac{28x^{10}+y^{10}+z^{10}}{30}$$
via the $n=30$ case of AM/GM. Do this for all three terms and add.

This method should prove your generalisation, and also work for other
values of $9$ and $10$.

Comment: Oh, neat way to write AM-GM there. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's just Muirhead because $$(10,0,0)\succ\left(\frac{28}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right).$$
In Muirhead it's better that exponents should be non-negative.

Variables in Muirhead must be non-negatives, otherwise the Muirhead inequality is wrong in the general.

Another way:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^{10}-x^9)=\sum_{cyc}(x^{10}-x^9-\ln{x})\geq0.$$

Comment: +1 Oh, sure, this way $x^{28/3}y^{1/3}z^{1/3}=x^{27/3}(xyz)^{1/3}=x^9$... So basically the exponents aren't necessarily  positive, but some sources define them as such just because the negative case is redundant, as it can be trivially transformed into the other case?

Comment: @Mr. Xcoder Exactly! From here it's better to work with non-negative exponents.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, can you explain what you are doing with the $\ln x $ manoeuvre in your answer? Why is the expression $\ge 0$?